# how can I filter the nth element of an array located inside of another array?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to filter the data I am using in a D3 line chart.
My data (caled 'slices') is an array of 8 object, each objet has two keys ('id' and 'values'), the value of the key 'values' is another array of 46 objects
[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoneC.png)

My question is, how can I filter the nth element of 'values'?

what I can do is :

```
slices.filter(function(d,i){return i%3 == 1})
```

but this is filtering every 3 elemets of the top level, I get 3 results because there are only 8 elements, I dont want this. I want to filter every 3 elements in 'values' (all the 46 objects arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you will have to use:

```js
slices.map(
  ({id, values}) => ({
    id,
    values: values.filter((_, i) => i%3===1)
  })
)
```

Now why this:

Your data structure looks like:

```
[{
  id: "",
  values: [...]
}]
```

and when you say *how can I filter the nth element of 'values'?*, it essentially means you need all values in `slices` to have updated value for `values`.

So you will have to follow these steps:

1. Loop over `slices` and return processed values
2. In the loop, create new object that needs to be returned.
3. Filter `values` based on your logic
4. Set this value to `values` property of returned value